# Need help resolving RAILS 3.0.9 migration issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, migration, stack, rake

I'm having some serious rails issues.  I haven't used it in quite some time so I went through and updated rvm, rails, etc.  I'm currently running the following:

```
RVM -- rvm 1.6.25 by Wayne E. Seguin (wayneeseguin@gmail.com) [https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/]

RAILS -- Rails 3.0.9

RUBY -- ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0]
```

I perform the following steps:

```
rails new my_project

cd my_project

bundle install

rails g scaffold person first_name:string last_name:string

rake db:migrate

/Users/devuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/version.rb:4: warning: already initialized constant MAJOR
/Users/devuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/version.rb:5: warning: already initialized constant MINOR
/Users/devuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/version.rb:6: warning: already initialized constant BUILD
/Users/devuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/version.rb:3: warning: already initialized constant NUMBERS
/Users/devuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/version.rb:9: warning: already initialized constant VERSION
/Users/devuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake.rb:26: warning: already initialized constant RAKEVERSION
/Users/devuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/early_time.rb:17: warning: already initialized constant EARLY
/Users/devuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/alt_system.rb:32: warning: already initialized constant WINDOWS
/Users/devuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:28: warning: already initialized constant DEFAULT_RAKEFILES
WARNING: Possible conflict with Rake extension: String#ext already exists
WARNING: Possible conflict with Rake extension: String#pathmap already exists
/Users/devuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task_arguments.rb:73: warning: already initialized constant EMPTY_TASK_ARGS
/Users/devuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/invocation_chain.rb:49: warning: already initialized constant EMPTY
/Users/devuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:10: warning: already initialized constant RUBY
/Users/devuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:84: warning: already initialized constant LN_SUPPORTED
/Users/devuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/dsl_definition.rb:143: warning: already initialized constant Commands
/Users/devuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_list.rb:44: warning: already initialized constant ARRAY_METHODS
/Users/devuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_list.rb:47: warning: already initialized constant MUST_DEFINE
/Users/devuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_list.rb:51: warning: already initialized constant MUST_NOT_DEFINE
/Users/devuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_list.rb:55: warning: already initialized constant SPECIAL_RETURN
/Users/devuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_list.rb:61: warning: already initialized constant DELEGATING_METHODS
/Users/devuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_list.rb:364: warning: already initialized constant DEFAULT_IGNORE_PATTERNS
/Users/devuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_list.rb:370: warning: already initialized constant DEFAULT_IGNORE_PROCS
/Users/devuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake.rb:64: warning: already initialized constant FileList
/Users/devuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake.rb:65: warning: already initialized constant RakeFileUtils
rake aborted!
stack level too deep
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Remove rake 0.9.2 and install rake 0.8.7 and see if it works.

Comment: It's telling me I can't uninstall rake...I tried "rvm gem uninstall rake -v 0.9.2" and it uninstalled it from all rails versions but two.  And when I run "gem uninstall rake" it simply laughs at me.  The error is:  "cannot uninstall, check `gem list -d rake`".  Thoughts?

Comment: Alright, I wasn't aware that I was supposed to use the "Installed at:" to perform an uninstall.  Anyway, feel free to post your answer as an answer so I can credit you with points, etc.  Thanks again!  =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove rake 0.9.2 and install rake 0.8.7 and see if it works.

The rake 0.9.x branch has been well known to break any rails install completely.

Answer (score 3):

Solution copied from my blog: http://joneslee85.wordpress.com/2011/07/29/howto-fix-rake-0-9-2-to-work-with-ruby-1-9-2-under-rvm/

**BEST WAY:**
I do not think reverting to 0.8.7 is the best answer because if you compile 1.9.2 with RVM, you will bump into this issue. Here is how to fix this babe:

- `gem list | grep 'rake'` and you will see this `rake (0.9.2 ruby)`. Now please carefully pay attention to the keyword "***ruby***" is the evil-doer, it's actually the duplication of rake in @global folder. I think this could be RVM bug.
- Now we need to remove rake, please do: `gem uninstall rake`, say Y when it warns that it will break dependencies and also say Y if it asks to remove the executable 'rake'.
- Now, check again `gem list | grep 'rake'` and you will simply see `rake (0.9.2)`

That would fix this issue.

**SECOND WAY: Revert to 0.8.7**

Okay, you WILL NOT be able to uninstall rake 0.9.2 because RVM installed rake into `@global` folder. So here is how you can delete rake 0.9.2 manually before installing rake 0.8.7:

```
gem list -d rake
```

and pay attention to the *Installed at: /Users/mojo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global* in the output. Yours will differ from mine so please be aware, now we need to remove rake with following commands:

NOTE: make sure you escape the character @ with an \

```
rm /Users/mojo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290\@global/bin/rake
rm /Users/mojo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290\@global/cache/rake-0.9.2.gem
rm -rf /Users/mojo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290\@global/doc/rake-0.9.2/
rm -rf /Users/mojo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290\@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/
rm /Users/mojo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290\@global/specifications/rake-0.9.2.gemspec
```

Next is to install rake 0.8.7 with `gem install rake -v=0.8.7`

Comment: You're "BEST WAY" answer is perfect. You indeed hit the nail on the head with that one. Much better solution than the other accepted options.